# Second model within the same form returns invalid on powershell

Tags: python, django

im having trouble with getting the 2nd model within the same form being valid. Can anyone help? The 1st model device_frm works well. It saves the info I need in the table I want. But the 2nd model does not even get saved. Appreciate if anyone can help to solve this issue. Been stuck on this for days

views.py

```
def device_add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    device_frm = DeviceForm(request.POST) ##Part A1
    dd_form = DeviceDetailForm(request.POST)
    if device_frm.is_valid():
        device_frm.save()
        deviceid = Device.objects.aggregate(Max('id')) 
        device = Device.objects.all() ##Part A1
        if dd_form.is_valid():
            deviceD = dd_form.save(commit=False)
            deviceD.device = Device.objects.get(id=deviceid)
            deviceD.save()


        return render(request, 'interface/device-added.html',{'devices':device})
   

else:
    device_frm = DeviceForm()
    dd_form = DeviceDetailForm()
    di_frm = DeviceInterfaceForm()
    return render(request,'interface/device_add.html',{'form':device_frm, 'dd_form': dd_form})
```

models.py

```
  class Device(models.Model):
        hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        ipaddr = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.hostname
    
  class DeviceDetail(models.Model):
            hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            mgt_interface = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            mgt_ip_addr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
            subnetmask = models.CharField(max_length=30)
            ssh_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            ssh_pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            enable_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            dev_mod = models.CharField(max_length=50)
            device_model = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            
            def __str__(self):
                return self.hostname
```

forms.py

```
class DeviceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Device
        fields= ['hostname', 'ipaddr'] 

class DeviceDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= DeviceDetail
        fields= ['hostname', 'mgt_interface', 'mgt_ip_addr', 'subnetmask', 'ssh_id', 'ssh_pwd', 'enable_secret', 'device_model']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        hostname = cleaned_data.get('hostname')
        if len(hostname) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Hostname needs to be more than 8 character long, {hostname}')
        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(dd_form.errors)`?

Comment: Found the error and solve that part but now im encounting another error. deviceid = Device.objects.aggregate(Max('id')) is not returning me a number for me to use for id=deviceid. It is now returning a value of 'id__max':75. How do i solve this?

Comment: And for the foreign key in my model, I cant use this as a text field? Or a field to select a option?

Comment: `deviceid = Device.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))['id__max']`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the 2nd question. Can you edit your post and add more details?

Comment: Sorry. Because in my models.py. device_model is used as a foreign key currently. My question is, is it possible for a foreign key to be used in a form as text? Like user can type a text for device_model and it get saved? Basically can it still function as other variables such as mgmt_ip_addr etc

Comment: No. Since it's a foreign key, it can be only be an id of `Device`. Why do you want to do this? How about just adding another field?

Comment: I tried adding another field but here comes my question. If i add another field in the form. Say dev_mod. Meaning my form will have a text input for user to enter. How do i use the foreign key then? Under the DeviceDetailForm, do i take in device_model in the field? If not how do i use it. After all this device_model in the one that link 2 tables together

Comment: Can you explain again why you need this text input? Is this to change the relationship between `Device` and `DeviceDetail`?

Comment: This is for the form. The form i have requires the following text inputs:
hostname,
ipaddr,
mgt_interface,
mgt_ip_addr,
subnetmask,
ssh_id,
ssh_password,
enable_secret,
dev_mod (The model of the device)

The foreign key is for me to link the device and devicedetail table together. For the device table, i have to store hostname & ipaddr. The devicedetail table has to store rest of the remaining fields

Comment: It seems your current form is already doing that (`device_model` is in `fields` of `DeviceDetailForm`). What's not working?

Comment: Im not sure on how to use the foreign key. Do i include it under the field in form?

Comment: It's already there (device_model in fields of DeviceDetailForm)

Comment: Currently it is working in a form where i get to select the previously store hostname. Is that how its suppose to work?

Comment: Yes, it seems because in `Device`, the `__str__` returns `self.hostname`, that's why you see the hostname

Comment: Ok thank you very much for all ur explanation! Also thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: No worries! Have fun

Comment: Sorry I got a question regarding this again. If lets say in my models.py, i dont return self.hostname and in the form i dont request for foreign key, how does the foreign key works? Does it just link up the 2 tables at the back without using it in forms?

Comment: Not sure but I don't it will link those up automatically, as it doesn't know which device it will link to.

Comment: Hmm make sense. Is it possible if i do this? The form i have currently to POST for 2 models. And within this 2 models, they both have hostname. So for the 1st model, device-hostname the same. But for the 2nd model, devicedetail, hostname is the foreign key instead and remove this return hostname. Does this foreign key still works as intended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235638/discussion-between-calvin-lin-and-bdbd).